# Access a global variable located in the head of Index file within Angular2 component?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to access a variable declared in the head of the Index file from within an Angular2 Component.

```
<script>
    var DATA = {
         foo: 'bar'
    };
</script>
```

I have tried declaring the variable inside the component with

```
declare var DATA: any;
```

However, accessing the variable inside my constructor remains "undefined". I should also mention this variable is being declared by the server. We are utilizing Angular Universal for pre-render.

Comment: Why cannot you declare this variable in the component instead?

Comment: It is being rendered by the server.

Comment: Look at this article. https://juristr.com/blog/2016/09/ng2-get-window-ref/. You will need to expose the `window` object and then access the variable through it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you may try below,

```
console.log(window.DATA);
or
console.log(window["DATA"]);
```

to get strongly type add below in `typings.d.ts`,

```
declare interface Window {
    DATA: { foo: string};
}
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Property 'DATA' does not exist on type 'Window'. is the error I get when I try this.

Comment: That is a typescript error, you may add it in your typings file. or else try using `window["DATA"]`

Comment: window["DATA"] worked. I will accept answer when possible. There was an error in a JSON variable declared before the variable I was trying to access that resulted in the "undefined" issue.